# Should I buy an aftermarket cooler?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I need a solution for cooling the i7-4790k.
I am worried about the temperature of the CPU core going beyond 95°C (not fahrenheit).
Should I buy an aftermarket liquid cooling for my CPU for lowering the temperature or should I buy an air based cooler? The ambient temperature in the room is around 32°C - 37°C.

Comment: What temperature does the room reach without aircon? Before investing in a new cooler, I'd be inclined to replace the thermal paste with some high quality & see if it does any better - old, cracked or cheap paste is often a cause of high temps.

Comment: Thats higher than usual. There isn't really enough information though - are you running the system overclocked? Would adjusting the overclock be an option? What options have you looked at so far?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - semi overclocking condition you can say .... i think the stock cooler is not up to the mark in cooling down the temps..

Comment: @Tetsujin normal temps 32 to 37 max .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal experience, for mid/heavy tasks, the stock cooler while it does do the job at preventing the CPU from overheating and shutting down the system (in most cases) doesn't keep it that cool.

If you really want very low temps even at high loads, I would recommend an aftermarket cooler in a heartbeat.

Comment: yeah .. somewhat heavy multi tasking .. i guess the stock cooler is not doing the job .. so is there any suggestion on best cooler for cpu like - corsair or cooler master or any ???

Comment: Well first up you need to decide whether you want air cooling or move over to liquid. Liquid tends to get EXTREME cool temps, hence why overclocks love it. The only downside is that it might not fit in some cases. Air is great because it fits almost any config, some bulky ones though might interfere with the RAM (which is why low profile RAM is a thing). Tower style coolers work real well as they go with the airflow of the overall case and some support multiple fans for increased cooling performance.

Comment: My personal preference is Corsair as I have used it in many builds and am satisfied with their cooling performance in many scenarios and build quality as well. In the end though it does come down to personal preference and price as well. Doing a quick Google on the cooler you chose for reviews on them is a good idea to get a ROUGH idea on how they preform against other coolers alike.

Comment: Alrighty then i will go for hydro cooler .. thanks for briefing me about the pros of it .. appreciate for your valuable time ! Cheers ...

Answer (score 0):

just get a good fan (around 50 USD). and redo the thermal paste as suggested in the comment.
that should work in 99% of the cases 
for that 1% that it doesn't work you should just replace the CPU assuming that intel's lifetime warranty will be honored where you bought it.
any hydro / nitro whatever fans are meant for non-standard use like overclocking etc.